# Convert HashMap into String with keys and values

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I want to create util method which converts HashMap into long String with keys and values:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedhashMap<>();

map.put("first_key", "first_value");
map.put("second_key", "second_value");
```

I need to get this end result:

```
first_key=first_value&second_key=second_value
```

Comment: you know that if you call the toString() method of the map you allready get
```{first_key=first_value, second_key=second_value} ```

Comment: URLEncoding is more complex than that.

Comment: Are you using this for generating a query string? If so, you also need to consider URL-encoding special characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use streams:

```
String result = map.entrySet().stream()
   .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue())
   .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

---

**Note**: You should probably use an url encoding. First create a helper method like this:

```
public static String encode(String s){
    try{
        return java.net.URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

And then use that inside of your stream to encode the key and value:

```
String result = map.entrySet().stream()
   .map(e -> encode(e.getKey()) + "=" + encode(e.getValue()))
   .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

Comment: Yes, How I can set them to UTF-8?

Comment: I get `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)` here map.entrySet().stream()

Comment: By the way what will happen if there are empty spaces or `-` into the keys or values?

Comment: @PeterPenzov the spaces will be encoded to `%20`, and the minus will stay

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    sb.append(entry.getKey());
    sb.append('=');
    sb.append(entry.getValue());
    sb.append('&');
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: If there are no entries in the map then this will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
map.toString().replace(",","&")
```

Comment: The leading and trailing brackets `{}` need to be removed too, e.g. by substring

Answer (score 0):

The output `Map::toString` is not much different from the output you want. Compare:

- `{first_key=first_value, second_key=second_value}`
- `first_key=first_value&second_key=second_value`

Just perform the right character replacement:

```
map.toString().replaceAll("[{ }]", "").replace(",","&")
```

- `"[{ }]"` is regex matching all the brackets `{}` and the space  - those to be removed (replaced with `""`).
- `,` to be replaced with `&` character.

Comment: Could lead to problems when trying to send strings with spaces or brackets, or commas in them

Comment: @Lino: Possibly. Applicable well to the OP's example as an alternative solution. The character escaping is another issue.